# How to display all Wordpress posts with own custom key

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to get and display all posts by my own custom key "expiration_date".

I use **WCK plugin** for adding my custom keys. I've added two fields: **expiration_date** and **price**.

I tried to write it by myself and I created my owf function 'courses_by_date' in template **function.php** file and display courses_by_date(); in **content-page.php** file, when I want to display all posts with added these above two fields.

**Very important:** some posts may have several pairs of fields: expiration_date and price.

Now, I can display only the first pair of these fields of each post with these keys.

```
function courses_by_date() {    
    $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => 'expiration_date');
    
  $posts_array = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts_array as $i => $post)
  {
    echo $i . " <a class='title' href='https://post-url.com'>" . $post->post_title . "</a> | " . $post->expiration_date . ", price: " . $post->price . " EUR " . "<br>";        
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display posts that both `expiration_date` and `price` contain or any of them contain?

Comment: All my posts have both fields and I want to display them like this: Title with post url, date, price

Comment: So you want only to get those posts that have `expiration_date` and `price`?

Comment: Yes, I want to get posts which have these key-pair and display x times (how many times these keys are set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass increment params at end of the meta key. check below code.

```
function kursy_wg_daty() {
    $a = 0;

    echo "<ul>";
    while($a < 20) {
        if($a == 0) {
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => 'expiration_date');
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            foreach($posts_array as $post){
                echo "<li> <a class='title' href=" . post_permalink($post) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a> | " . $post->expiration_date . ", price: " . $post->price . " zł " . "</li>";
            }
        } else {
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => "expiration_date" . "_" . $a);
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            foreach($posts_array as $post) {

                $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration_date_'.$a, true );
                $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_'.$a, true );

                echo "<li> <a class='title' href=" . post_permalink($post) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a> | " . $expiration_date . ", price: " . $price . " zł " . "</li>";
            }
        }
        $a++;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it displays only once the post - even if it has 2 or 3 fields with date and price. I need to display 3 times the post if it has 3x same fields ```expiration_date``` and ```price```

Comment: How many posts do you have with both keys?

Comment: Posts <20, but each post has 2-3 dates and prices.

Comment: what do you mean by 2-3 dates?

Comment: One post can have multiple keys "expiration_date" and "price", both as pair. For example: ((expiration_date: 2021-03-31 (12:00-13:00), price: 359), (expiration_date: 2021-04-08 (9:00-11:00), price: 399)).

Comment: I tested and working fine for me I added expiration_date and price in three posts and all are displaying.

Comment: It displays each post x times (how many times you've added the pair of these keys)? For example: 3 pairs of expiration_date and price in 3 posts and you get list with 3x3 = 9 elements?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots with DB meta and posts?

Comment: Sure, some screenshots from DB [URL](https://imgur.com/a/3NxfKRC)

Comment: And for example: a post with post_id 150 may have multiple expiration_date and price key-pairs.

Comment: can you put your tried code in question? and also what is your post_type?

Comment: post_type of all my post I needed is just 'post'. My actual code is in my question above.

Comment: I also paste the screenshot from my admin panel [URL](https://imgur.com/a/jz0KPpM) - there are fields from WCK - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Creator plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230511/discussion-between-bhautik-and-miro).

Comment: OK, I see. Based on one post with 3 expiration_date and price keys: ```0)``` expiration_date and price, ```1)``` expiration_date_1 and price_1, ```2)``` expiration_date_2 and price_2. So only the first pair of keys in this post have a name like that, each next one has a digit _1, _2, _3 ...