# How to sort Wordpress array with posts by own custom key

Tags: php, wordpress

**I'd like to sort an array with posts by own custom key 'expiration_date'**

```
function kursy_wg_daty() {
    $a = 0;
    $todayDate = date("Y-m-d");

    echo "<ul>";
    while($a < 20) {
        if($a == 0) {
            // posts with single expiration_date
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => 'expiration_date');
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            
            foreach($posts_array as $post){
                $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration_date_'.$a, true );
                $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_'.$a, true );

                $only_date = substr($expiration_date, 0, 10);
                $time = strtotime($only_date);
                $newFormatDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                                
                if ($newFormatDate > $todayDate)
                {
                    echo "<li> <a class='title' href=" . post_permalink($post) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a> | " . $post->expiration_date . ", price: " . $post->price . " zł " . "</li>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            // posts with more than one expiration_date
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => "expiration_date" . "_" . $a);
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            
            foreach($posts_array as $post) {
                $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration_date_'.$a, true );
                $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_'.$a, true );
                
                $only_date = substr($expiration_date, 0, 10);
                $time = strtotime($only_date);
                $newFormatDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                                
                if ($newFormatDate > $todayDate)
                {
                    echo "<li> <a class='title' href=" . post_permalink($post) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a> | " . $expiration_date . ", price: " . $price . " zł " . "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        $a++;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

**Now the effect looks like:**

- Kurs A | 2021-04-10 (08:30-9:45), price: 190 zł
- Kurs B | 2021-04-09 (12:00-13:00), price: 359 zł
- Kurs C | 2021-04-16 (08:30-9:45), price: 150 zł
- Kurs B | 2021-04-15 (09:00-11:00), price: 399 zł
- Kurs D | 2021-04-08 (11:00-12:30), price: 370 zł
- Kurs D | 2021-04-12 (11:00-12:30), price: 230 zł
- Kurs D | 2021-04-17 (09:00-11:00), price: 180 zł

**but it should be sorted by 'expiration_date' - so in my code it is $newFormatDate, like this:**

- Kurs D | 2021-04-08 (11:00-12:30), price: 370 zł
- Kurs B | 2021-04-09 (12:00-13:00), price: 359 zł
- Kurs A | 2021-04-10 (08:30-9:45), price: 190 zł
- Kurs D | 2021-04-12 (11:00-12:30), price: 230 zł
- Kurs B | 2021-04-15 (09:00-11:00), price: 399 zł
- Kurs C | 2021-04-16 (08:30-9:45), price: 150 zł
- Kurs D | 2021-04-17 (09:00-11:00), price: 180 zł

This question is associated with my previous question [How to display all Wordpress posts with own custom key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843843/how-to-display-all-wordpress-posts-with-own-custom-key)

Comment: `'expiration_date_'.$a, true `or `expiration_date" . "_" . $a` or it should be `expiration_date` with out `_`

Comment: It's good, because based on one post with 3 expiration_date and price keys: `0)` expiration_date and price, `1)` expiration_date_1 and price_1, `2)` expiration_date_2 and price_2. So only the first pair of keys in this post have a name like that, each next one has a digit _1, _2, _3 ...

Comment: okay, when i run into conflict with WordPress scripts, i first create what i want without WordPress language the after working it correctly , i turn  the script to WordPress functions as i want.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the variable, now it's okay.

Comment: yeepe, i was correct. its good you seen it too

Comment: Does this issue is resolved?

Comment: No, above is the actual code and I need to sort these posts by `expiration_date` as in question.

Comment: @Bhautik do you have idea how to do this?

Comment: I will back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `array` and push all values to that array then sort an array by datetime. Try the below code.

```
function function kursy_wg_daty() {

    $a = 0;

    $todayDate = date("Y-m-d");

    $postIds = array();

    while($a < 20) {

        if($a == 0) {
            // posts with single expiration_date
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => 'expiration_date');
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            if( !empty( $posts_array ) ){
                foreach($posts_array as $post){

                    $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration_date_'.$a, true );
                    $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_'.$a, true );

                    $only_date = substr($expiration_date, 0, 10);
                    $time = strtotime($only_date);
                    $newFormatDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                                    
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['datetime'] = $newFormatDate;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['id'] = $post->ID;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['post_title'] = $post->post_title;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['link'] = get_the_permalink();
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['expiration_date'] = $expiration_date;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['price'] = $price;           
                }
            }
        } else {
            // posts with more than one expiration_date
            $args = array("posts_per_page" => 20, "meta_key" => "expiration_date" . "_" . $a);
            $posts_array = get_posts($args);
            if( !empty( $posts_array ) ){
                foreach($posts_array as $post) {

                    $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration_date_'.$a, true );
                    $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_'.$a, true );
                    
                    $only_date = substr($expiration_date, 0, 10);
                    $time = strtotime($only_date);
                    $newFormatDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                                    
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['datetime'] = $newFormatDate;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['id'] = $post->ID;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['post_title'] = $post->post_title;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['link'] = get_the_permalink();
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['expiration_date'] = $expiration_date;
                    $postIds[$post->ID]['price'] = $price;

                }
            }
        }
        $a++;
    }

    array_multisort( array_map( 'strtotime', array_column( $postIds, 'datetime' ) ), SORT_ASC, $postIds );

    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ( $postIds  as $key => $post ) {
            if ( strtotime( $post['datetime'] ) > strtotime( $todayDate ) ){
                echo "<li> <a class='title' href=" . $post['link'] . ">" . $post['post_title'] . "</a> | " . $post['expiration_date'] . ", price: " . $post['price'] . " zł " . "</li>";
            }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    
}
```

**Updated as per OP request.**

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
 
$field_name = 'post_id';
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
 
$get_all_posts = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%expiration_date%' ORDER BY meta_value ASC " );
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $get_all_posts, ARRAY_A );

echo "<ul>";
    foreach( $post_ids as $postmeta ){

        $expiration_date = get_post_meta( $postmeta['post_id'], $postmeta['meta_key'], true );

        $last_value = substr($postmeta['meta_key'],-1);

        if( is_numeric( $last_value ) ){
            $price = get_post_meta( $postmeta['post_id'], 'price_'.$last_value, true );
        }else{
            $price = get_post_meta( $postmeta['post_id'], 'price', true );
        }

        $only_date = substr($expiration_date, 0, 10);
        $time = strtotime($only_date);
        $newFormatDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);

        echo "<li><a class='title' href=" . get_the_permalink( $postmeta['post_id'] ) . ">" . get_the_title( $postmeta['post_id'] ) . "</a> | " . $newFormatDate . ", price: " . $price . " zł " . "</li>";

    }
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but your code works now like that: if I add three dates and prices to one post I can see only the last one.

Comment: Hmm, but not for me. I pasted your code and I see only last pair(date + price) of each post...

Comment: can you screenshot of current results?

Comment: Sure https://imgur.com/bZPwlSW - each of these "Kurs" has more than one date and price but I can see only the last one of each.

Comment: And no one urls of these posts doesn't work (they have base url like "/")

Comment: Do you know how many `expiration_date_` and `price_` keys will be per post?

Comment: I think it will be less than 20 per post. First pair is `expiration_date` and `price`, if post has more than one key-pair it will be `expiration_date_1` and `price_1` and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231198/discussion-between-bhautik-and-miro).

Comment: Above version doesn't read `price` for first pair, `expiration_date` is ok but empty price, because in above code reads only `price_` key, but first pair in each post has key `price` (without underscore "_").

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I will back to you.

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.